# Почему input type="file" отображается по-разному в разных версиях Microsoft Edge?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Edge Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393
[image: Edge Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393]
Проверяю на  https://saucelabs.com и вижу нормальный результат (Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 13.10586)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема и как это исправить ?

```css
.hide-input {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
 
.fileInput {
    background: #789fc3;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #fff;
    width: 188px;
    border: none;
    padding: 11px 35px 9px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px #f5f5f5;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload_photo" class="hide-input"/> 
<label for="upload_photo" class="fileInput">Загрузить фото</label>
```

Comment: Добавьте для `.hide-input` свойство  `visibility:hidden` или `display:none`

Comment: я вот недавно смотрел видео о том что добавлять для таких случаев `display:none` типа плохо, но да ладно, если это поможет, то огромное спасибо

Comment: Оно плохо в том смысле, что в старых браузерах может не сработать. Но `visibility:hidden` должно нормально быть

Comment: @Yuri А может добавите ваш комментарий как ответ, как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что в старых браузерах `z-index` в отрицательном числе не сработает.
Вам нужно добавить к элементу `.hide-input` один из следующих стилей:

1. `display: none` (но с этим стилем **может не сработать нажатие в
   старых браузерах**)
2. `visibility:hidden`